# IndexedDB one library called from multiple different places with different callbacks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, chaining

So I have this JS indexedDB library:

```
window.db = {
    name:"indexedDBname",
    varsion:0.7,
    _settings:"indexedDBobject",

    h:null, // Handler to the db

    open:function(callback,callback1) {
        var r = indexedDB.open( db.name );

        r.onupgradeneeded = function(e){ console.log(".onupgradeneeded is not yet supported by webkit"); };
        r.onsuccess = function(e){
            db.h = e.target.result;

            if( db.version !== db.h.version ) {

                var v = db.h.setVersion( db.version );
                v.onsuccess = function(e) {
                    if(db.h.objectStoreNames.contains( db._settings )) db.h.deleteObjectStore( db._settings );
                    db.h.createObjectStore(db._settings, { keyPath:"name" });
                };
                v.onfailure = db.onerror;
                v.onerror = db.onerror;
                v.onblocked = db.onerror;
            }

            // CALLBACKS
            if(typeof callback=="function" && typeof callback1=="function") callback.call(window,callback1);
            else if(typeof callback=="function" && typeof callback1!="function") callback.call(window);

        };
        r.onfailure = db.onerror;
    },
    getSettings:function(callback){ // retrieve user custom settings
        var t = db.h.transaction( [db._settings], IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY ),
            s = t.objectStore(db._settings),
            keyRange = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(0),
            cursorRequest = s.openCursor(keyRange),
            tmp = {};

        cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
            var result = e.target.result;
            if(!!result==false) {

                // CALLBACKS
                if(typeof callback=="function") callback.call(window);

                return;
            }
            tmp[result.value.name] = result.value.value;
            result.continue();
        }
        cursorRequest.onerror = db.onerror;
    },
    onerror:function(e){ console.log("Handle and print error here:"+e); }
};

// actual run
db.open( db.getSettings, user.applySettings);
```

Which I tend to use pretty often, but as you can see, those callback doesn't look too well... And when I want to do series of tasks or even call any of those functions with set of their own parameters, my code starts to look really choppy, ex. 
`db.open('forWhichUser',newSettingsToApplyObject, callback1, argumentForCallback1, secondOptionalArgument, callback2, etc);`

So in the old days I'll just do:

```
db.open('userName', settingsMap);
var opts = db.getSettings();
user.downloadInfoBasedOn( opts );
user.renderInfoTo('userDataHolderId');
```

but now, since everything can start/finish in unpredictable moments (depending on computer performance, db size, etc, etc...) how do I handle all of that asynchronicity keeping code graceful and readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript promises/deferreds pattern:

1. http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx

Promises/deferreds can help you create a much easier and readable async code. You can use jQuery deffered object to achieve that (http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Another option is to use story.js which wrap the IndexedDB API and exposes it in a much simpler way (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2012/04/21/the-story-begins.aspx)

I hope you will find this answer helpful.

Gil

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I've been looking for! I'm glad to give you your first 25 points ;)